# Как создать ярлык на рабочем столе?

Tags: java

Хотелось бы узнать, можно ли средствами Java, создавать ярлыки на рабочем столе?
Т.е. нажал кнопку - создался ярлык.

Comment: А вот интересно, что общего между созданием ярлыка на рабочем столе Windows, KDE, Gnome и т.д.

Comment: Что мешает создать файл с нужным расширением и прописать внутри то, что необходимо от ярлыка (то бишь ссылку на этот самый файл) ?

Comment: ну интересен именно ярлык

Comment: без понятия, у меня винда стоит.. пока что

Comment: наверное потому, что я пишу на java ;)

Comment: ... даже если писать приходится на "выжрал васике". Хоть поменяйте язык на JScript -- винде всё равно, а вам привычней.

Comment: причём тут javascript?? у меня программа на java и нужно было подходяще решение.  
То что там есть вставка VBS - ну и что, главное задачу свою выполняет.

Comment: Ну во-первых не javascript, а JScript, а во-вторых, чтобы Ваша программа заработала на моём компутере, потребуется немало телодвижений. Да и не только на моём.

Comment: это же обычный текстовый файл

Answer (score 2):

#### Какой класс и метод использовать для создания ярлыка?

Для создание ярлыка можно воспользоваться методом [createSymbolicLink()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createSymbolicLink-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-) из класса `java.nio.file.Files`. Этот класс появился в `java-7` и содержит методы для работы c файлами.

Сигнатура у метода такая:

```java
public static Path createSymbolicLink(Path link, Path target, FileAttribute<?>... attrs)
        throws IOException
```

О параметрах (взято из документации):

- link - это путь, по которому будет создан ярлык;
- target - путь к объекту (файлу или папке), "куда будет вести ярлык";
- attrs - атрибуты для ярлыка. В данном случае это так называемые вараги (*varags*), поэтому атрибуты можно и не указывать.

#### Как пользоваться методом `createSymbolicLink()`?

Чтобы создать ярлык, нужно произвести следующие шаги:

1. Так как метод принимает `java.nio.file.Path`, то нужно сначала получить такой два объекта `Path` (объект файла и объект ярлыка) Делается это с помощью метода `get()` класса `java.nio.file.Paths`:

```java
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.io.File;

....

Path file = Paths.get("C:" + File.separator + "Файл.txt");
Path link = Paths.get("C:" + File.separator + "Ярлык");
```

2. Создайте файл (например, с помощью метода `createFile()` из того же класса `java.nio.file.Files`) и ярлык. Но не забывайте, что оба метода бросают **проверяемое** исключение `java.io.IOException`, поэтому вам придётся его обработать:

```java
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.io.IOException;

...

try{
    Files.createFile(file);
    Files.createSymbolicLink(link, file);   
} catch (IOException e){
    System.err.println("Не удалось создать файл или ярлык! Более подробная информация:");
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

#### Результат:

[image: Результат]

#### Ссылки

- [java.nio.file.Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html)

  - [createSymbolicLink()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createSymbolicLink-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-)
  - [createFile()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createFile-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...-)
- [java.nio.file.Path](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html)
- [java.nio.file.Paths](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html)

#### P.S

Если хотите создавать ярлык по нажатию кнопки - то поместите вызов методов в обработчик нажатия кнопки =). А на счёт рабочего стола - просто пропишите путь до рабочего стола, а не до диска `C:\`.